# Instagram API Tag search query stopped working after recent update

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Not long ago I used the following request to fetch some data for my application:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/mytag/media/recent?access_token=mytoken

Now I am greeted with the following response:

```
{"meta": {"error_type": "OAuthPermissionsException", "code": 400, "error_message": "This request requires scope=public_content, but this access token is not authorized with this scope. The user must re-authorize your application with scope=public_content to be granted this permissions."}}
```

It seems I must have my application approved by Istagram to have access to the data I want.

**So is this the only currently supported way to keep my application working?**

I am grateful for any help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, after June 1st 2016, all apps have to be reviewed by Instagram and approved to get API access

If not you can only access your latest 20 posts using API (sandbox mode)

https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/